# How do I give a UISwitch an inner shadow using SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

The current `UISwitch` in iOS 13 looks like this

[image]

and I want to give the `UISwitch` an inner shadow (using SwiftUI **NOT UIKit**) so it looks like this

[image]

but I have no idea how I would go about doing so.

Comment: Have you tried to modify it ? `Toggle().shadow(radius: 5)`